# SQLPlus Spool CSV adding new line in columns

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I need your help in spooling SQL output to formatted CSV below is the query producing the results -

```
set linesize 800
set pagesize 0 embedded ON
set underline off
col USERNAME format A12
COL USER_ID HEADING 'ID'
col USER_ID format 999
COL PASSWORD HEADING 'PWD'
col PASSWORD format a03
col ACCOUNT_STATUS format a18
col DEFAULT_TABLESPACE format a9
col DEFAULT_TABLESPACE heading 'DEF_TBS'
col TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE format a7
col TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE heading 'TMP_TBS'
col profile format a8
col INITIAL_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP format a22
col INITIAL_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP heading 'INIT_RSRC_CONSUMER_GRP'
col EXTERNAL_NAME heading 'EXT_NAME'
col EXTERNAL_NAME format a2
col EXPIRY_DATE heading 'EXP_DATE'
col PASSWORD_VERSIONS heading 'PWD_VERS'

set flush off
set echo off
set term off
set colsep ';'
set trimspool on

SELECT
  u.username, u.user_id, u.account_status, u.created, u.lock_date, u.profile,
  MAX(DECODE (up.resource_name, 'FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS', up.limit, '')) FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS,
  MAX(DECODE (up.resource_name, 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME', up.limit, '')) PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME,
  MAX(DECODE (up.resource_name, 'PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION', up.limit, '')) PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION,
  MAX(DECODE (up.resource_name, 'PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME', up.limit, '')) PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME,
  MAX(DECODE (up.resource_name, 'PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX', up.limit, '')) PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX,
  MAX(DECODE (up.resource_name, 'PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME', up.limit, '')) PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME,
  MAX(DECODE (up.resource_name, 'PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME', up.limit, '')) PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME
FROM dba_users u
INNER JOIN (SELECT p.profile, p.resource_name, DECODE(p.limit, 'DEFAULT', pd.limit, p.limit) limit
            FROM dba_profiles p
            LEFT JOIN dba_profiles pd ON p.resource_name = pd.resource_name AND p.resource_type = pd.resource_type AND pd.profile = 'DEFAULT'
            WHERE p.resource_type = 'PASSWORD') up ON u.profile = up.profile
GROUP BY u.username, u.user_id, u.account_status, u.created, u.lock_date, u.profile;
```

The above code is resulting below csv -[image] here columns are breaking in newline instead single rwo header, which is not expected.

```
USERNAME    ;  ID;ACCOUNT_STATUS    ;CREATED  ;LOCK_DATE;PROFILE ;FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS                                                                                                           ;PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME                                                                                                             ;PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION
PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME                                                                                                              ;PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX                                                                                                              ;PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME
PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME
```

The expected result is -
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV Spooling is restored with correct alignment after the below parameters appended

```
col USERNAME for a25
col FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS for a25
col PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION for a25
col PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX for a25
col PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME for a25
col PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME for a25
col PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME for a25
col PROFILE for a18
col PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME for a25
```